# SDK initialization outside as didFinishLoadingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I must keep `AppDelegate` class intact (I do not own it), So I can't have my SDKs initialized as part of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but I want a similar effect

Basically I can only add files to the project not alter them (that why I use the `+load` function)

Is it safe (and considered a good practice) to:

1. Register To `NSNotificationCenter` `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` during objective-c `+load`
2. Trigger SDK initialization code (under a dispatch_once predicate)

Here is the code:

```
+(void) load{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}    
+ (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotificationCenter *)notification{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

      // ran some SDKs initializations code
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you like to achieve with it?

Comment: @holex - See edit in question

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in AppDelegate which is already called when ever the application did become active:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Therefore, No, this is not a good practice.

In addition you are registering the class as an observer. Such things should be done by an instance of a class, for example by the AppDelegate.

Comment: thanks @dasdom Take a look at my Edit on the question, and also why can't I register the class instance as the observer?